# Count number of rows with NaN in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, nan

Having the following running code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

my_funds = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 11]
my_time = ['2020-01', '2019-12', '2019-11', '2019-10', '2019-09', '2019-08']
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': my_time, 'FUNDS':my_funds})

for x in range(2,3):
    df.insert(len(df.columns), f'x**{x}', df["FUNDS"]**x)

df = df.replace([1, 7, 9, 25],float('nan'))

print(df.isnull().values.ravel().sum())   #5 (obviously counting NaNs in total)
print(sum(map(any, df.isnull())))         #3 (I guess counting the NaNs in the left column)
```

I am getting the dataframe below. I want to get **the count of the total rows**, with 1 or more NaN, which in my case is **4**,  on rows - `[0, 2, 3, 4]`.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df.isna().any(axis=1).sum())
4
```

**Explanation**: First compare missing values by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):

```
print (df.isna())
    TIME  FUNDS   x**2
0  False   True   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True
3  False   True  False
4  False   True  False
5  False  False  False
```

And test if at least per rows is `True` by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df.isna().any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

And last count `True`s by `sum`.

Comment: Sounds like it. What was the `ne(0)` in the previous edit?

Comment: @Vityata - it was [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), but now solution is simplier and faster

Comment: And what is the idea of `print(sum(map(any, df.isnull()))) ` producing 3?

Comment: @Vityata - It seems it test columns names only, same output if `print (list(map(any, df)))`, `print (list(map(any, df.columns)))`

Comment: What do you mean columns names? `[TIME, FUNDS, x**2]` are not NaN?

Comment: @Vityata - yes, because if use `df.columns = [0,1,2]` it fail, but I dont remember explantion.

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
nan_rows = len(df[df["FUNDS"].isna() | df["x**2"].isna()])
```

Comment: I like the `or`, it looks sql-ish :)

Comment: here is better use `any`... think if you have to test more columns

Answer (score 1):

#### **New option [`Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html)**

to take one when there is more than one `NaN` per row

```
df.isna().sum(axis=1).clip(upper=1).sum()
#4
```